# Параметр sysctl fs.quota.syncs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ядро

Не могу найти однозначный ответ о параметре fs.quota.syncs

За что отвечает и является ли он настроечным параметром или счётчиком?

На разных серверах разное значение. После перезагрузки - значение 0. Что намекает на то что это счётчик.